# How can I calculate the distance of each observation from the centroids created by scipy.cluster.hierarchy?

Tags: scipy, distance, hierarchical-clustering, centroid

I have a vector `x` which represents text data transformed with tf-idf.
Then I calculate the distance between all points of the vector using `cosine_similarity()` function of sklearn and create the `linkage_matrix` of the ward distance using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`. This creates an hierarchical clustering, but I can not figure out how to calculate the distance of each observation from each centroid.

When using kmeans from sklearn I figured out that I can caluclate this by calling the `transform()` method for the `x` vector, which then returns a matrix with the euclidean distance between each observation and each cluster. I would like to do something similar using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` algorithm.

I have tried examining the `linkage_matrix` returned, as well as the `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`, but it does not seem to be what I need.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Z = fcluster(ward(X), threshold, criterion )
```

threshold : maximum distance between two points in a cluster

Z is 1-D array which assigns cluster number to each point. Now you can estimate distance:

- Take a cluster
- Find its centroid
- Find the  distance (same as criterion, I am not sure what criterions mean in scipy library) of centroid from points

Furter REading:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster